# $(0,1]$ is not homeomorphic to $(a,b)$ - Carothers Example 5.6(g)

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, analysis, metric-spaces

I'm reading Carothers' Real Analysis, and I'm currently looking at **homeomorphisms**. The author says "two intervals that look different, are different" - i.e. they are not homeomorphic. The proof is done for the case $(0,1]$ and $(a,b)$, where the first interval is semi-open so we expect that the two are not homeomorphic.

I have some difficulty following the book's argument which I paraphrase here (for convenience) with inline questions.

> Proof by contradiction. Suppose $(0,1]$ and $(a,b)$ are homeomorphic. Then by removing $1$ from $(0,1]$ we get $(0,1)$, and by removing its image $f(1) = c$ from $(a,b)$ we have that $(0,1)$ is homeomorphic to $(a,c)\cup (c,b)$.

Wait, why is that? I understand that we are deleting an element each from the domain and codomain, so the bijection remains a bijection. What about the continuity of $f$ and $f^{-1}$ though? We literally threw away an element, how do we know that continuity still holds?

> But $(0,1)$ is homeomorphic to $\Bbb R$, so $\Bbb R$ would have to be homeomorphic to $(a,c)\cup (c,b)$ too. So $\Bbb R$ can be written as the disjoint union of two non-trivial open sets, which is impossible.

Two questions:

1. Why is $(0,1)$ homeomorphic to $\Bbb R$? We really need to produce a homeomorphism, that's all I'm asking.
2. How to prove that $\Bbb R$ cannot be written as the disjoint union of two non-trivial open sets? The idea that comes to my mind is - we already know that any open subset of $\Bbb R$ can be written as the disjoint union of unique open maximal intervals. Since $\Bbb R$ is open in $\Bbb R$, we can obviously do the same for it as well, and clearly, our choice of intervals would not be maximal in the event that we could write $\Bbb R$ as the union of two disjoint open intervals. Does this make sense?

Thank you!

Comment: I do not have access to Carother's book, but via a preview in the internet I have seen that there is a whole chapter about "connectedness". I would be surprised if that would not contain a proof that real intervals are connected.

Comment: This example is from the chapter preceding Connectedness, I haven't gotten there yet.

Comment: Okay, then you should read chapter 6. I think it does not make much sense to write an answer here - it will contain nothing else than the book. But you can also look at https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3943095 .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

0. Continuity still holds when you remove a point, because the restriction of a continuous map is still continuous.
1. A homeomorphism between $(0,1)$ and $\mathbb{R}$ is given by
   $$x \mapsto \tan \left(-\frac{\pi}{2}+t\pi \right)$$
2. $\mathbb{R}$ is connected, so cannot be written as the disjoint union of two non-trivial open sets.

Answer (score 1):

In $\Bbb R^2$ let $C$ be the circle centered at $(0,2)$ with radius $1.$ Let $D=\{(x,y)\in C: y<2\}$...Now $D$ is a semi-circle without its end-points, and $D$ is homeomorphic to $(0,1).$

For $p\in D$ let $l_p$ be the line thru $p$ and $(0,2)$ and let $l_p$ intersect the $x$-axis at $(f(p),0)$... (Draw a diagram of this.)

$f: D\to \Bbb R$ is a homeomorphism. A composition of homeomorphisms is a homeomorphism, so if $g: (0,1)\to D$ is a homeomorphism, then so is $(fg):(0,1)\to\Bbb R.$